# When you save values not as key:value pairs but only as key it saves them as keys within a JS object right?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, javascript-objects, variable-assignment

For example when you have an object

```
const obj = {
   time,
   difficulty,
   distance,
}
```

The values that are inside of the object are saved as keys, correct?
If I was to call Object.keys() on the object I would receive array of individual string elements?

Comment: Yes, [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) will return an array own enumberable `keys`

Comment: Firstly: yes. Secondly: why not just run that code and see for yourself!?

Comment: Did you try it? By trying it you would answer your own question.

Comment: That's a shorthand notation for `time: time, difficulty: difficulty, ...`

Answer (score 1):

Using that notation, the property `name` will be the key, and the property `value` will be the value.  This syntax was introduced in ES6.

It is the same as

```js
const obj = {
 'time': time,
 'difficulty': difficulty,
 'distance': distance
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `Object.keys()` it returns an array of the property names, not their values.

You can use an object like an associative array to make it act like a key/value pair.

```
someObject[“someKeyName”]
```